# Connecting S3 - Lambda - EC2 - Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, elasticsearch, amazon-s3

In my project users upload images into a S3 bucket.  I have created a tensor flow resnet model to interpret the contents of the image.  Based on the tensor flow interpretation, the data is to be stored in an elasticsearch instance.

For this, I have created a S3 Bucket, a lambda function that gets triggered when an image is loaded, and AWS elasticsearch instance.  Since my tf models are large, I have zipped them and put it in a S3 bucket and uploaded the s3 url to lambda.

Issue:  Since my unzipped files were larger than 266 mb, I could not complete the lambda function.

Alternative approach:  Instead of S3 Bucket - I am thinking of creating a ec2 instance - with larger volume size to store images and receive the images directly into ec2 instance instead of s3.  However, since I will be receiving images in millions within a year, I am not sure if this will be scalable.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two approaches here:

1. You side load the app. The lambda can be a small bootstrap script that downloads your app from s3 and unzips it. This is a popular pattern in server less frameworks. You pay for this during a cold start of the lambda so you will need to keep it warm in a production env.
2. You can store images in s3 itself and create event on image upload with destination SQS. Then you can use ec2 to pull the sqs messages for new messages periodically and process them using your tf models.